# Opencv android aplication crashes on new activity

Tags: java, android, opencv

I followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6ywepfA_PU) but I put the opencv code in another activity that can be accessed by a main menu. As soon as I switch to that activity the app crashes.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;


public class testActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
public void onManagerConnected(int status){
        switch (status){
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
        }
    }

};
private JavaCameraView mOpenCvCameraView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    mOpenCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.testVideoView);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallback);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {

}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    return inputFrame.rgba();
}
}
```

logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity 
{bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester/bluemage.systems.
displaylatencytester.testActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: 
   Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND }
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
           (ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be 
    explicit: Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND }
        at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1680)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1779)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1757)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
        at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper.initOpenCV(AsyncServiceHelper.java:24)
        at org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.java:79)
        at bluemage.systems.displaylatencytester.testActivity.onResume(testActivity.java:78)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1257)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6076)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2975)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}
```

Change `targetSDKVersion` to `19`

Comment: Change `targetSDKVersion` to `19` or use latest version of the library.